# Cant set and get value using dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms, user-controls

This dropdown list is inside a gird view:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Hello" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("beta") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="-">-</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0">0</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1">1</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Every time it has to load the page containing this gridview I get exception:

```
{"'beta' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.\r\nParameter name: value"}
```

The value of `beta` is null, however,

```
<asp:ListItem Value="null" Text="null">null</asp:ListItem>
```

Doesnt work... **Note** `beta` comes from database as the next possible values: null, 0 or 1 .Also tried getting the values from another dropdown list but doesnt work, i tried this:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i]; //this is inside a for loop
var ddl = row.Cells[8].Controls[0] as DropDownList;
string test= ddl.SelectedIndex;
```

I allways get `ddl` as null when debugging.

So the questions are:

**1.** How to load the dropdown with 3 values one of them beeing null?

**2.** How to read the selected dropdown value without using any events like onchange or whatever, example:

```
  CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
  bool isChecked = chk.Checked;
```

Comment: First question answer you can't `null` represents a empty object and either  one the one you have mentioned in Value and Text **null** is actually a string. You can overcome null by using nullable operator and assign default value like `<%# Eval("beta") ?? "1" %>`

Comment: @Suprabhat yea got that but is there any way to get it as null? The 'beta' field is in fact `boolean?` so it can be: true|false|null

Comment: Like i said assign default value like modifying your markup `<asp:ListItem Value="" Text="-1">-</asp:ListItem>` and use `<%# Eval("beta") ?? "-1" %>`

Comment: @Suprabhat yea just tried it but still same error pff

Comment: Ok, i got it in my previous comment i have assigned a default value in text field `<asp:ListItem Value="" Text="-1">-</asp:ListItem> ` but i am selecting it by value modify your markup to this `<asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="--">-</asp:ListItem> `

Answer (score 0):

To answer you quetsions:

1. You can't set `null` as a value for a ListItem, because `null` is not a string literal. `null` means that the value is missing. `null` itself is "not a value". So you will need to handle that in your code:

   `drpList.SelectedValue = dbObj.FieldValue ?? "(n/a)";`
2. I'm not sure what you are asking here. I would suggest using [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of using indices to access your controls.

Answer (score 0):

As for your problem,  Refer below article for dropdownlist in asp.net

http://www.laptrinhdotnet.com/2015/07/su-dung-control-dropdownlist-trong.html

Comment: this is more like a comment.